# React setState callback runs multiple times for the same update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came across a weird issue when updating a state in both useEffect and a callback. This is React 18 (automatic batching) with strict mode off.

Here's a demo: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-grass-fyfm58?file=/src/App.js)

```
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const [state2, setState2] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state2) {
      console.log("effect");
      setState(s => {
        console.log("effect setState", s);
        return [...s, "effect"];
      });
    }
  }, [state2]);

  return (
    <input
      onMouseDown={() => {
        setState2(1);
      }}
      onFocus={() => {
        console.log("focus");
        setState(s => {
          console.log("focus setState", s);
          return [...s, "focus"];
        });
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

When clicking the input, `onMouseDown` runs before `onFocus`. I expect it to log:

```
effect
focus
effect setState []
focus setState ['effect']
```

However, it's logging:

```
effect
focus
focus setState []
effect setState []
focus setState ['effect']
```

Why is it running the `setState` callback twice in `onFocus`? I couldn't find any mention of this behavior in the React docs or Github, I'm assuming this is related to concurrent mode? This is causing subtle bugs that's hard to explain in a SO question.

Comment: Given the end state is the same, why does it matter? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) unless you actually care about console logs (which you shouldn't). My guess is React reconciles the `focus setstate` running on a previous render by re-running it on the latest

Comment: Is that the actual order of the console logs in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your [modified sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-driscoll-ngwjpq?file=/src/App.js), now including the current render iteration...

```js
const render = React.useRef(0);
render.current++;
```

which is logged along with a `performance.now()` high-resolution timestamp

```js
console.log(render, performance.now(), "<message>", ...);
```

You can see the results in the console...

```
1 2971 "mousedown" 
2 2974 "effect" 1
2 2978 "focus" 
3 2978 "focus setState" []
4 2982 "effect setState" []
4 2982 "focus setState" (1) ["effect"]
```

The clue is in this statement regarding [batching](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#react-batches-state-updates)

> React does not batch across multiple intentional events

I think what you're seeing is *similar* to when React uses [strict mode](https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#what-happens-if-you-replace-state-after-updating-it)...

> In Strict Mode, React will run each updater function twice (but **discard the second result**) to help you find mistakes.

In this case, the different events are executing close together (but not simultaneously) so in order to avoid issues, React is discarding the state update for a stale render (#3) and re-running the batch queue.

Given the end state is the same as the one you expect, I fail to see how any of this is a problem though it is certainly an interesting observation.